# How to force Windows XP to login into the domain upon boot, and then self-lock

Tags: windows-xp, domain

Is it possible to force an XP machine on a domain to login as a certain user and then lock upon boot?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [AutoAdminLogon feature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) for an automatic logon. Locking could be accomplished by either setting up a screen saver which would fire after a short period of time and lock the workstation or by using [`psshutdown -l`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) upon logon. Note that psshutdown requires administrative rights, so you would need to use the [Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) to create a task that is run at interactive logon in the security context of the SYSTEM user. This is especially useful if you can't trust the user to have logon scripts run without interruptions (i.e. if you expect someone at the console who would be preventing script execution).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [autologon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) and [lock](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/windows_user/f747.shtml).